# How can store and use variable and subroutine names in a Perl hash?

Tags: perl

My program processes two flavors of 'something' and each flavor has its own data structures and procedures for processing them. User invokes the program with either or both of:

- `-f1 path_to_file_with_flavor_1_data`
- `-f2 path_to_file_with_flavor_2_data`

My program is working coded as:

```
GetOptions ('f1=s' => \$f1_path,
            'f2=s' => \$f2_path,
           );

if (defined $f1_path) {
  subroutine_to_process_flavor_1_data( $f1_path );
}
if (defined $f2_path) {
  subroutine_to_process_flavor_2_data( $f2_path );
}
```

It has a single hash to store the processed data for both flavors:

```
my %flv_hash = ( flavor_1 => { datahash => { ... },
                             },
                 flavor_2 => { datahash => { ... },
                             },
               );
```

I now want to add each flavor's variable and subroutine names to the hash to make it:

```
my %flv_hash = ( flavor_1 => { datahash => { ... },
                               var_name => 'f1_path',
                               sub_name => 'subroutine_to_process_flavor_1_data',
                              },
                 flavor_2 => { datahash => { ... },
                               var_name => 'f2_path',
                               sub_name => 'subroutine_to_process_flavor_2_data',
                              },
               );
```

and change my program to below pseudo-code:

```
foreach my $flavor ( keys %flv_hash ) {
   if (defined <the variable named $flv_hash{flavor}{var_name}>) {
      <call the subroutine named $flv_hash{flavor}{sub_name}>
   }
}
```

I have searched all knowledge bases on the subject of storing and retrieving the names of variables and subroutines in a hash but, being a hardware engineer whose software skills are limited to what I learned in Basic Programming 101 that I took some 35 years ago, I couldn't directly copy the examples and get them to work in the context of my program. Another words, if possible I'd appreciate a solution I can just copy and use without having an in-depth knowledge of the Perl paradigms on which they are based. Thank you again.

Comment: Are you sure you want the _names_ instead of references to the subroutines? `\subroutine_to_process_flavor_1_data` instead of `'subroutine_to_process_flavor_1_data'` is usually more useful.

Comment: Hi Ted, yes references would be fine, as long as you provide the syntax.

Comment: `my $ref = \&subroutine_to_process_flavor_1_data;` (I missed the `&` above). and then call the sub: `&$ref( arguments );`

Comment: Thank you, Ted. Any idea how to handle the variable in  'if (defined  ) ' statement?

Comment: You could use the built in reflection and `eval` the name into a variable but I find that unnecessary 99.99% of the time. Just make `var_name` a reference too, like you did when you used `GetOptions`. Another option is to make `GetOptions` call the subroutine directly: `GetOptions ('f1=s' => \&subroutine_to_process_flavor_1_data, ...`.
You can even write the subroutine inline: `GetOptions ('f1=s' => sub { ... }, ...`

Comment: put your options into a hash and use that instead `GetOptions(\%opts, 'f1=s', 'f2=s') ... my %flv_hash = ...'var_name' => 'f1' ... if (defined $opts{$flv_hash{$flavor}{'var_name'})`

Comment: As an alternative to calling a subroutine reference with `&$subref(args)`, most people seem to prefer `$subref->(args)` (as it looks more like how most people use array and hash refs - `$arr_ref->[index]` and `$hash_ref->{key}`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The one thing that is off in that nice layout is the use of *names*, for the subroutine and for the variable, in forming the hash -- you can't actually use those things then, to run the subroutine or evaluate the variable, with just their bare names.

Instead, you can take a *subroutine reference*, which is a scalar and thus can be a hash value, and then the subroutine can be executed by dereferencing it; and use the variable as the value.

The hash

```
my %flv_hash = ( 
    flavor_1 => { 
        data => { ... },
        var  => $f1_path,
        code => \&subroutine_to_process_flavor_1_data,
    },
    flavor_2 => { 
        data => { ... },
        var  => $f2_path,
        code => \&subroutine_to_process_flavor_2_data,
    },
);
```

(that `code` for the key is but a placeholder for a better name).   To use this as indicated

```
foreach my $flavor ( keys %flv_hash ) {
   if (defined $flv_hash{$flavor}{var}) {
      $flv_hash{$flavor}{code}->( $flv_hash{$flavor}{var} );
   }
}
```

The `\&sub_name` syntax takes and returns a [reference to a subroutine](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References) and so is a scalar, which can be assigned and/or manipulated as any other scalar.

Another way of creating such a *code reference* is to use an [anonymous subroutine](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html), by directly assigning the subroutine code using syntax

```
my $code_reference = sub { subroutine-code };
```

what you could also do in your hash (`code => sub { ... }`) if the subs were short and sweet.

Then the notation `$coderef->( LIST )` is how we execute a subroutine with its reference in the scalar variable `$coderef`.  If there are no arguments we need empty parens.

There are of course a number of ways to organize this, once you adopt code references; I merely follow the reasonable intent from the question.  Another item that may be useful in this vein is the [dispatch table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table); one recent reference is on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60408256/4653379), and there are many more.

See also for example [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834590/why-would-i-use-perl-anonymous-subroutines-instead-of-a-named-one), and for far more [this article](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/09/enchant-closures-for-better-debugging-output/) from *The Effective Perler* ...etc.

---

It crossed my mind that perhaps the sub names themselves may be needed as well.

An easy way to retrieve a name from the code reference is with [Sub::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/Sub/Util.html)

```
use Sub::Util qw(subname);

say subname( $coderef );
```

This is in the core since, I think, perl-5.22.0 (?).  There is also [Sub::Identify](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Identify) on CPAN.

Then, the almighty [B](https://perldoc.perl.org/B.html) gives that and more via `svref_2oject($coderef)`, which for code reference returns a [B::CV](https://perldoc.perl.org/B.html#B%3a%3aCV-Methods) object, on which [B::GV](https://perldoc.perl.org/B.html#B%3a%3aGV-Methods) methods can be used as well

```
use B qw(svref_2object);

my $cv = svref_2oject($coderef);

say for $cv->FILE, $cv->GV->NAME;  # etc
```

Comment: zdim, your solution worked like a champ and I learned a few things in the process. Thank you much.

Comment: @hw_engineer_trying_to_write_sw  Great, I'm very glad for it and thank you for saying that :).  Let me know what/if I can add -- it's hard for me to decide what can be useful, but without diluting the post beyond the purpose. (I will add some comments, at least)

Comment: @hw_engineer_trying_to_write_sw I had added a way to retrieve a name from a code reference.